# Can i add only xhdpi Icons to Cordova App?

Tags: cordova, icons, phonegap-build

I am working on bulk apps, and all of the apps are mostly for android platform 4+ , as per my knowledge 99% of the latest phones have 1080p or 720p screens, is it necessary to add low DPI icons as well ? what if i add only xhdpi icons .. ?

will it work ? will it support all the devices or it will not work on the 1% small screen devices ?

Please Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NK,
1) first as of this date (July 2015) there are still a large number of devices with a DPI of less than 720p. Your source information is likely biased. Just like Google's numbers are bias as to how many Android 2.x are still available.

2) Google recommends you use other DPI for the other devices. They will scale down, but you might have side effects.

3) Here is an alternative that someone has posted. This link will create your other DPI icons and splash screens.

*Generate Titanium icon & splash assets* 
http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/

Best of Luck,
Jesse

Comment: Thanks for your reply , that was helpful . but what if my apps target is KitKat only ?

can there be more than 5 % devices having Kitkat and less than 720 dpi ?

Comment: Good question, I can't say. But less than 720dpi is still cheap - overseas and for low-end items in the US. I recently bought a Sprouts Cubby at Walmart. I suspect they will sell a lot at $100 per unit. They claim 1024x600, but the screen is grainy and lumpy. I doubt it is 720dpi.  Then again, it is intended for kids... It has a rubber bumper case.  **Bottom line, you know your customer, I don't.** http://www.walmart.com/ip/Sprout-Channel-Cubby-7-Tablet-16GB/38573923

Comment: yup , you are right.. there are such devices... will go for two resolutions then.. but i don't find having 5 resolutions a good solution..

there should be a provision to have SVG , and Google should be responsible for re sizing ... anyways thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You should at least consider Android's Ninepatch. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html